# Query to update data in MYSQL database, search in table 1 , update in table 2, how?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to quickly change some stuff in a large wordpress database, doing through the GUI takes forever, i think executing this direclty on the database would be much more efficient as it's a one time thing.

I have the follow tables involved:

```
wp_posts
--------
ID
post_status

wp_termrelationships
--------------------
object_id
term_taxonomy_id
```

I need to execute a mysql query that looks for **term_taxonomy_id** '8232' in the table **wp_termrelationships** , if there's a match for **term_taxonomy_id** '8232' then take the **object_id** for that match and use that data to search table **wp_posts** column **ID** for a match. When matches are found in table **wp_posts** column **ID** update the **post_status** for each post to 'publish'

No changes is made to anything except the post_status in the table wp_posts.

To me this query is very complex, any ideas?

Comment: So the table "wp_posts" has no column "term_taxonomy_id" ? Then which column in table "wp_termrelationships"  holds the reference to the table "wp_posts"?

Comment: You're absolutely right, forgot that it has to be a reference between the 2, i have updated my main post to explain better, i hope that helps?

Comment: Wow, please edit the question and use block code to describe your tables, and separate text from code.  Right now it looks like gibberish.  Look at the edit tools help on the right of the edit window when you do.  If you see the format of the question is weird, image how it is for us that have no context in the question.

Comment: sorry, i updated it more clearly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets deconstruct your requirement, and build the queries:

> *I need to execute a mysql query that looks for term_taxonomy_id '8232' in the table wp_termrelationships*

```
SELECT object_id
FROM wp_termrelationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 8232
```

> *if there's a match for term_taxonomy_id '8232' then take the object_id for that match and use that to search table wp_posts column ID for the data gotten from the match in the object_id*

Here I use a sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
             FROM wp_termrelationships
             WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 8232)
```

> *when those matches are found update the post_status for each matched post in table wp_posts to 'publish'*

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_status = 'publish'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT object_id
             FROM wp_termrelationships
             WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 8232)
```

Here I take for granted that term_taxonomy_id is an integer.

Comment: This may be to much to ask as it may come off topic, but if i would want to test this query before i run it, is it enough by changing "UPDATE" to SELECT instead?

Comment: Yes indeed, the second `SELECT *` does just that.

Comment: getting an error running the select query : **/* SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row */ ** what would cause this issue? Multiple rows are expected!

Comment: @Nic3500 :: Nice answer! Very informative and complete. Well done.

Comment: Test query returned the values i was looking for, i think can be marked as solved, thank you very much for your extensive experise and help @Nic3500